# No se pueden agregar filas a un DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos

Tags: c#, datagrid

Estimados tengo el siguiente error, tengo datos en un DataGridView, y mediante un botón "Nuevo", se agrega una nueva fila; pero me sale el siguiente error:

**No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe resaltar que mi grilla tiene ComboBox que llenan desde la BD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como hago para llenar una nueva fila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si asignaste el `DataSource` no puedes usar el `Rows.Add()` tiene que asignar el nuevo dato como parte del `origen de datos`, si es un `DataTable` lo recuperas y agregas alli mismo.

Algo como esto

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvVinculados.DataSource;

var row = dt.NewRow();
row["cod_corr"] = txtRucDni.Text;
row["Nombres"] = dgvr.Cells["Nombres"].Value;
//resto
dt.Rows.Add(row);

dgvVinculados.DataSource = dt;
```

Nota: no se si los nombre de las columnas del datatable son las correctas, es solo un ejemplo el que puse

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini gracias por responder, probé tu código si llegó agregar una nueva línea, hasta aquí todo perfecto; pero al agregar la nueva línea copia los mismos datos que ya hay en una fila, el tema es que agregue una nueva fila vacía, o al menos un dato repetido en la fila, es decir:  La columna **COD_CORR** que se repita en la nueva fila pero las demás que estén vacías, te agradecería de antemano.

Comment: hay parte del codigo que esta oculto en la imagen, pero debes validar que row del grid estas seleccionando, si quieres agregar una fila vacia a las columnas no le asignes ningun dato

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro Tuttini, como siempre ayudando a resolver los problemas, ya quedó mi código.